# Data masking using PostgreSQL at Amazon RDS, how to?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, masking, data-masking

I was looking into this

https://postgres.ai/docs/database-lab/masking

and was searching how to mask (dynamically) my data using Amazon RDS PostgreSQL, but couldn't find any real solution.

Is there any one out there that solved that without recurring to server/backend masking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve readonly masked data I'd say to use views from the PostgreSQL. One way to achieve that would be:

1. Create a new schema, for example: "masked"
2. Create a new view inside the masked schema, with the same name as the table you want to mask your data dynamically. You'll set your masked rules on this said view.
3. Create a new user role which will retrieve the masked data and change its search_path to look first for the masked schema `SET search_path TO '$user', masked, public`

This way, if you make a query to select from the said table, it'll first look for the masked schema and if it has a view with the same name as the table you are doing your query, it'll retrieve the masked data from the rules applied to the view.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. Can you post an example?

Comment: Sure.
Let's say you have a table called "Customers" and you want to mask it. You first create a new schema "masked", and then you create a new user "maskeduser" and set his search path to look first to masked schema, and then for the public schema (which is the DEFAULT one). Then, you create a view with the same name as the table, which in our case is "Customers", and you apply your mask rules into this view. 

Now, when maskeduser makes a query looking for Customer data table, it'll retrieve the data following the mask rules you set on the view.